# Blazor app getting ERR_CONNECTION_RESET on dll file

Tags: c#, asynchronous, blazor

I have a blazor app that sometimes gets a ERR_CONNECTION_RESET on a specific dll and fails to launch.

This does not happen in every machine, and sometimes in the same browser but on different machines, it does not open also.

The dll in question is in the correct directory.

What troubles me more is the "randomness" of the error, since we are unable to find why in some machines it works and others it does not.

Here is a pic of the error.

Thanks to everyone that can help.

[image]

Comment: We are experience the same issue, did you find any solution?